# ST terminal is showing '?' for powerline git status

Tags: git, archlinux, powerline

I am using ST terminal and dwm in arch linux. I have installed powerline and git status with

```
pip install powerline-status
pip install powerline-gitstatus
```

But terminal is showing '?' for git status.

[image]

I have tried to add powerline fonts from the git repo with

```
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git --depth=1 fonts
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Getting the fonts onto your own machine is a good first step, but you must make sure that your terminal actually *uses* those fonts (that usually involves installing them as user fonts and configuring whatever you use for the terminal to make use of one).